# Integrating databases in different locations to create a unified database

Tags: database, machine-learning, bigdata, integration

I am working on a research project where we are trying to build a machine learning model for a disease prediction. For this we have data from hospitals around the country. The problem is each hospital is having their own database model(RDBMS, Nosql), different column names for patient records. Are there any solutions available on how to integrate all this data to create a machine learning on top of it?

Comment: you can use SSIS

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of EHRs.